# Auto-refresh Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

refresh a spline Highchart and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. My code is this:

```
(function($){
    $(this.document).ready(function(){
        //get local time
        Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
        var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({

     chart: {
         type: 'spline',
         //animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
         marginRight: 10,
         renderTo: 'mychart',
         zoomType: 'x',
           events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = <?php echo strtotime($starttime)*1000;?>, // current time
                            y = 0;
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        min: <?php echo strtotime($starttime) * 1000; ?>,
        max: <?php echo strtotime($end) * 1000; ?>,
         //min: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
        //max: Date.UTC(2013,4,23),
    },
      yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Data Volume (KB)'
            },

        }], 
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        }, 
       title: {
            text: 'User Traffic'
        },
    series: [{
        name:'Hourly traffic',
        data:[<?php echo join(',',$traff); ?>],

        //pointStart: Date.UTC(15, 05, 15),
       // pointInterval: 24 * 3600  // one day
    }]
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

My series looks like this:

```
[1432034700000, 95.23],[1434034700000, 65.2],[1435034700000, 40.23] etc
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in the setInterval. I don't parse the data in the correct form or something like that.Also I'm not familiar with the syntax. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Thanx in advance!

Comment: You're not describing how it is "wrong". Does it not render at all? Is the point not added? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the error. It seems to render but In the process the x-lines are disappearing and also the line that connects the dots. It actually is part-working but with these problems. Also my x-axis is set to show  the hour every five minutes. How do I change that to show it every minute?

Comment: See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyvgnhpg/). This is your code without PHP. It seems to work as intended.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work in JSFiddle. I edited my code a little in x and y. Maybe the error is that the data is not live and I have to change it my self in the database constantly. Also I'm calling `highcharts.js` through Yii and not through that `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` so it maybe outdated or something. Anyway, thanks for the reply and the help!

Comment: The problem is in this line: `var x = <?php echo strtotime($starttime)*1000;?>` - your php will be generated once, when page is loaded. So you are adding points all with the same values. Instead, try this: `var x = new Date().getTime()`. Also, I suggest to remove `xAxis.max`. Otherwise you won't see new points, when new_point_x > xAxis.max.

Comment: I think I know what my problem is. I want to update the y inside the setInterval dynamically from the database! How can I achieve that? I keep searching in google but I can't seem to find a satisfying answer!

Comment: Load data from the server using AJAX. See [this tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) for more info.

Comment: thanks already tried that but I have other problems there. Your previous answer seems to work but it still messes with the animation. The line connecting the dots disappears and also the vertical lines. In JSfiddle it works perfectly but in my application the animation is screwed.

Comment: The problem was with my version of Highcharts in Yii. I have an older version installed. So the solution was to set `animation:false` and now everything seems to work fine. Thanks for all the help!